# How to add `killOp` privilege in mongo-atlas?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to add [killOp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#killop) privilege to my atlas M10(mongo version 4.0.19) cluster but I don't see the option in custom role manager. how to add killOp role to my cluster?

[image: here is the screenshot]

Comment: There is https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#killop under https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#deployment-management-actions, do you have any actions of this section in the UI?

Comment: no. I don't see any.

Comment: Maybe this is not allowed then. Are you a paying customer?

Comment: yes.i am a paying customer

Comment: I would ask this question using the official support channels.